# Idol worship temples by Hindus in Israel allowed?

Tags: avodah-zarah, state-of-israel

I read the current State of Israel allows idol worship in Israel by Hindus from India. What is the justification for same by State of Israel? And are Jews allowed to help them?

Comment: Justification? Israel is a mostly secular democratic country. Not much more to say.

Comment: It is a theocratic democracy right, so such a fundamental issue of avodah zarah is ignored?

Comment: In what way is it a theocratic democracy?